# check 2 columns script to run fast

Tags: python, loops, split, tuples

I have a script for checking 2 text files together and print out the common field. However I don't feel it is quick enough and I'm looking for optimization.

FILE1 (10k rows, 3 columns) and FILE2 (200k rows, 2 columns) with 1 field common to both files (csv files).

> FILE1:
>
> 92073263d,86674404000555506123,Communication
>
> FILE2:
>
> 163738212,7a93632111w7-01e7-40e7-9387-1863e7683eca
>   63729jd83,07633221122c-6598-4489-b539-e42e2dcb3235
>   8djdy37w8,2b8retyre396-2472-4b2d-8d07-e170fa3d1f64
>   92073263d,07633221122c-6ew8-4eww-b539-e42dsadsadsa

```
with  open('FILE1') as file1:
    file1_contents = { tuple(line.split(',')) for line in file1 }
    print file1_contents

with open('FILE2') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        c1,c2 = line.split()
     if c1 in  file1_contents:
            f = open("FILE3","w")
            f.write(c2)
            f.close()
```

this line if c1 in file1_contents is giving me a hard time as I want to avoid any nested loop to maintain high speed. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try using `pandas`...

Answer (score 1):

thanks COLDSPEED again..here is my new code:

```
import pandas

data_comreport= pandas.read_csv('FILE1', sep = ',', header = 0)  
data_db= pandas.read_csv('FILE2', sep = ',', header = None)
data_db.columns = ['SerialNumber', 'GUID']
data = pandas.merge(data_db,data_comreport,left_on = 'SerialNumber', right_on='SerialNumber', how='inner')
print data
#result = data.loc[data['FailureReason'] != ['Failure to export']]
#if result != None:
clean_data=data.to_csv('list.txt',index=False, columns=['GUID'],header = None)
```